# Azure KeyVault: how to create clientId and clientSecret?

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, azure-keyvault

I want to connect my application to KeyVault. Usually, I could create a **New Client Secret** and use it in my code.

```
var _keyVaultClient = new KeyVaultClient(
    async (string authority, string resource, string scope) =>
{
    var authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authority);
    var clientCred = new ClientCredential(clientId, clientSecret);
    var result = await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(resource, clientCred);
    return result.AccessToken;
});
```

I could create a [new client secret](https://www.puresourcecode.com/dotnet/azure/save-and-retrieve-secret-from-azure-keyvault/) from the Azure Portal.

[image]

Now, I can't find this option in KeyVault.

[image]

In *Program.cs* I have something like

```
var keyVaultEndpoint = new Uri(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("VaultUri"));
configApp.AddAzureKeyVault(keyVaultEndpoint, new DefaultAzureCredential());
```

Locally is working but when I deploy the application to Azure I have this error:

> Application '/LM/W3SVC/1699246683/ROOT' with physical root
> 'C:\home\site\wwwroot' has exited from Program.Main with exit code =
> '0'. First 30KB characters of captured stdout and stderr logs:
>
> [10:15:57 FTL] Host terminated unexpectedly
> Azure.Identity.CredentialUnavailableException: DefaultAzureCredential
> failed to retrieve a token from the included credentials.
>
> EnvironmentCredential authentication unavailable. Environment
> variables are not fully configured.
>
> ManagedIdentityCredential
> authentication unavailable, no managed identity endpoint found.
>
> SharedTokenCacheCredential authentication unavailable. No accounts
> were found in the cache.
>
> at Azure.Identity.DefaultAzureCredential.GetTokenAsync(Boolean isAsync,
> TokenRequestContext requestContext, CancellationToken
> cancellationToken)    at
> Azure.Identity.DefaultAzureCredential.GetTokenAsync(TokenRequestContext
> requestContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at
> Azure.Security.KeyVault.ChallengeBasedAuthenticationPolicy.AuthenticateRequestAsync(HttpMessage
> message, Boolean async)    at
> Azure.Security.KeyVault.ChallengeBasedAuthenticationPolicy.ProcessCoreAsync(HttpMessage
> message, ReadOnlyMemory`1 pipeline, Boolean async)    at Azure.Core.Pipeline.RetryPolicy.ProcessAsync(HttpMessage message, ReadOnlyMemory`1 pipeline, Boolean async)    at
> Azure.Core.Pipeline.RetryPolicy.ProcessAsync(HttpMessage message,
> ReadOnlyMemory`1 pipeline, Boolean async)    at Azure.Core.Pipeline.HttpPipelineSynchronousPolicy.ProcessAsync(HttpMessage message, ReadOnlyMemory`1 pipeline)    at
> Azure.Core.Pipeline.HttpPipelineSynchronousPolicy.ProcessAsync(HttpMessage
> message, ReadOnlyMemory`1 pipeline)    at Azure.Core.Pipeline.HttpPipeline.SendRequestAsync(Request request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at Azure.Security.KeyVault.KeyVaultPipeline.SendRequestAsync(Request request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at Azure.Security.KeyVault.KeyVaultPipeline.GetPageAsync[T](Uri firstPageUri, String nextLink, Func`1 itemFactory, String
> operationName, CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at
> Azure.Core.PageResponseEnumerator.FuncAsyncPageable`1.AsPages(String continuationToken, Nullable`1 pageSizeHint)+MoveNext()    at
> Azure.Core.PageResponseEnumerator.FuncAsyncPageable`1.AsPages(String continuationToken, Nullable`1
> pageSizeHint)+System.Threading.Tasks.Sources.IValueTaskSource<System.Boolean>.GetResult()
> at Azure.AsyncPageable`1.GetAsyncEnumerator(CancellationToken cancellationToken)+MoveNext()    at Azure.AsyncPageable`1.GetAsyncEnumerator(CancellationToken
> cancellationToken)+MoveNext()    at
> Azure.AsyncPageable`1.GetAsyncEnumerator(CancellationToken cancellationToken)+System.Threading.Tasks.Sources.IValueTaskSource<System.Boolean>.GetResult() at Azure.Extensions.AspNetCore.Configuration.Secrets.AzureKeyVaultConfigurationProvider.LoadAsync() at Azure.Extensions.AspNetCore.Configuration.Secrets.AzureKeyVaultConfigurationProvider.LoadAsync() at Azure.Extensions.AspNetCore.Configuration.Secrets.AzureKeyVaultConfigurationProvider.Load() at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.ConfigurationRoot..ctor(IList`1
> providers)    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.ConfigurationBuilder.Build()    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostBuilder.BuildAppConfiguration()    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostBuilder.Build()    at
> Skoruba.IdentityServer4.STS.Identity.Program.Main(String[] args) in
> C:\Projects\IdentityServer4\src\Skoruba.IdentityServer4.STS.Identity\Program.cs:line
> 26
>
> Process Id: 13436. File Version: 13.1.20234.8. Description: IIS
> ASP.NET Core Module V2 Request Handler. Commit:
> c75b3f7a2fb9fe21fd96c93c070fdfa88a2fbe97

Answer (score 7):

You are using `DefaultAzureCredential` which combines credentials commonly used to authenticate when deployed, with credentials used to authenticate in a development environment. The DefaultAzureCredential will attempt to authenticate via the following mechanisms in order.
[image: diagram containing sequence]

The reason it works in your local is most probably it's able to authenticate using one from your local box (the orange ones above).

Now for deployed environment, you need to do either of the following:

1. Setup [Managed Service Identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/overview) and give access to Key vault. For example, in Azure App Service, enable that from Identity blade in portal and then assign access policy in the key vault (identity name will be same as the App Service name).

Or, 2. Set client credentials in [Environment Variables](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/master/sdk/identity/Azure.Identity/README.md#environment-variables) (e.g. in App Settings in case of Web App).

Comment: @Enrico, If it helped, please consider [accepting the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) to conclude the thread.